# Java Azure AD OpenId connect gives 302 redirect code

Tags: java, azure, adal

I am new to Azure web application development.
 I am trying to do AD authentication with Java + Tomcat + Spring application according to the Azure [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java/).The same code is working fine with my first project.

Now I am trying to follow the same step to create second application.But after login its not going to next page of application.Even though the user information is coming null.And the final URL code is coming 302 code.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler for debugging. Also take a look at the Java sample here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect.git